# How to find the most viewed questions in an certain time?

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer

For example, I want to find which are the most viewed question on Stack Overflow today or the most viewed question of the month. With all the views not inside the interval being discarded.

I found this that could be helpful https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries
but don't know how to structure a query to get this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the Posts table has the ViewCount attribute depicting the latest viewcount for a question.

The ViewCount isn't stored in PostHistory or other tables for that matter, so we have no way to find view counts for a question in a certain time interval. The Stack API doesn't have this data either.

See also [Is it possible to use SEDE to plot the pageviews for a specific question over time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292366)